# Getting raw pointer from boost::gil::view

Tags: c++, boost-gil

I have a `boost::gil::view` which is interleaved. I want to construct my own model from this view which accepts the `byte*` of raw pixel data. How can I get the raw data pointer from `boost::gil::view`? I checked its interface, it returns locators and all, but not the raw data pointer. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out the way to do it. I used `gilView.row_begin(0)`